# Facing issue in custom sorting (in comparator) in pivot table

Tags: pivot-table, ag-grid, comparator, external-sorting, event-hooking

Hi I am using aggrid with react. And I am facing issue in custom sorting (in comparator). While doing grouping in pivot table I am trying to use comparator in autoGroupColumnDef, but it is not getting called. Can someone help me to resolve the issue

I am trying to implement custom sorting on grouping column, there customisation is must for my project requirement.

Comment: Can you add some of your code? This way it's easier to help.